# Haskell show instance on list

Tags: haskell, data-structures, instance

I'm having issues with adding a show instance to my data structure, which is:

```
data Structure = Structure String [Structure]
```

and I would like to have this output:

```
strct  
    strct1  
    strct2  
    strct3
```

I've been trying this

```
instance Show Structure where  
    show (Structure a (xs)) = show a ++ "\n" ++ "  " ++ show xs
```

But its output is

```
"strct"  
    ["strct1"  
    [], "strct2"  
    []]
```

So, I would need no brackets, no commas and no quotation marks. Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't use `Show` for pretty printing. There are pretty printing libraries available that will make this much easier for you.

Comment: so i guess every structure should have one level deeper indent?

Comment: I wouldn't! However, my teacher told me that I need to code it this way... @ReinHenrichs

Comment: Exactly @HuStmpHrrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are better library routines for this, but wouldn't this work?

```
unlines $ a : ["  " ++ show x | x <- xs]
```

However, that covers only one level. You probably want to define a different function than show to maintain the indentation, or you'd have to keep splitting sub-shows with `lines` to find where to inject indentation.

A rough draft of such an indentation insertion function is:

```
prefix p s = unlines [p ++ l | l <- lines s]
```

Again, I'm sure there's something better in a library. Even these short snippets have gone through a few steps of refinement (`foldl1 (++)` -> `concat` -> `unlines`, then join the first line as head with `:`).

Comment: It does work, thank you! However, it adds a new line at the end of each structure. Do you have an idea of how can I fix that?

Comment: First (silly) thought: Cut off the last character using `init`?

Comment: Second thought: `unlines` is essentially `concatMap (++"\n")`. That last `\n` could be skipped with `foldl1 (\a b -> a++"\n"++b)`. Which would of course be more legible as [`intercalate "\n"`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=intercalate).

Comment: @YannVernier note that `unlines` is not *essentially `concatMap (++"\n")`, it is **exactly** that. From [the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#unlines): `unlines                 =  concatMap (++ "\n")`

Comment: At least there was an ifdef with an alternate version. ;) Honestly, for the standard library to hold code you might write is a strong point of Haskell; it means the compiler will do well with many things we come up with also.

Answer (score 3):

Basically there only one bookkeeping to do, i.e. keep tract of the indentation level. An accumulative counter definitely helps:

```
pretty' :: Int -> Structure -> [String]
pretty' level (Structure s list) = ((concat $ replicate level "    ") ++ s) :
    (list >>= (pretty' (level + 1)))
```

This function defines an accumulator of your pretty printer. The remaining part is to wrap it:

```
pretty = pretty' 0
prettyShow = unlines . pretty
```

It definitely works

```
Prelude> putStrLn $ prettyShow (Structure "a" [Structure "b" [Structure "c" []], Structure "d" []])
a
    b
        c
    d
```

Comment: I just realized the part of my discussion of catamorphism is wrong, so I removed it. the recursion should be heterogeneous. but the remaining part is working and should be enough to answer OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `Data.Tree` module that comes with `base`. It is a generic (rose) tree with a structure identical to yours, except that the list goes by a type synonym:

```
data Tree a = Node {rootLabel :: a, subForest :: Forest a}
type Forest a = [Tree a]
```

It also comes with the `drawTree` and `drawForest` functions which are roughly what you were trying to write yourself.

```
> :m + Data.Tree
> let t = Node "strct" [Node "strct1" [], Node "strct2" [], Node "strct3" []]
> putStr . drawTree $ t
strct
|
+- strct1
|
+- strct2
|
`- strct3
```