# instance Show haskell

Tags: haskell

I got a data type "Cake"

```
*data Cake = EmptyBox | Food { name :: String
                                , flavors :: [Cake]} deriving( Read, Eq)*

instance Show Cake where
  show cake = prints cake where
   prints (Food name []) = name ++ "\n"
```

I want to print cakes like this (each cake got different flavors)

```
Cake1
  Chocolate
  Nutella
    Strawberry
Cake2
  Chocolate
  Vanilla
Cake3
```

But I got error, doesn't works! How can I do it?

Comment: Good, you are showing your code. But what error are you getting?

Comment: Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’ on   "show cake = prints cake where"

Comment: You should avoid using `show` for pretty printing. There was a recent question that answered nearly this exact question though. Can you extrapolate [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370551/haskell-show-instance-on-list)?

Comment: If that doesn't help, you need to write an MCVE. Note that the "V" there is "Verifiable" -- write something we can *run*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For test data, I used:

```
cake1 = Food{name="Cake1"
            ,flavors=[Food{name="Chocolate"
                          ,flavors=[]}
                     ,Food{name="Nutella"
                          ,flavors=[Food{name="Strawberry"
                                        ,flavors=[]}]}]}
cake2 = Food{name="Cake2"
            ,flavors=[Food{name="Chocolate"
                          ,flavors=[]}
                     ,Food{name="Vanilla"
                          ,flavors=[]}]}
cake3 = Food{name="Cake3"
            ,flavors=[]}
```

and wrote `Show Cake` as `unlines` composed with a function that has type `Cake -> [String]`

```
instance Show Cake where
  show = unlines . prints where
    prints :: Cake -> [String]
    prints EmptyBox    = []
    prints (Food s []) = [s]  -- a Food with no subflavors 
    prints (Food s fs) = s:concatMap (map ("  "++) . prints) fs
```

That last line handles the general case of a `Food` with name `s` and flavors `fs` by mapping `prints` over `fs`, then mapping `("  "++)` over each sublist in that map, and concat'ing them together.

```
("  "++)                             :: String -> String
map ("  "++)                         :: [String] -> [String]
map ("  "++) . prints                :: Cake -> [String]
map (map ("  "++) . prints)          :: [Cake] -> [[String]]
concat . map (map ("  "++) . prints) :: [Cake] -> [String]

concatMap = concat . map
concatMap (map ("  "++) . prints)    :: [Cake] -> [String]
```

Each successive level of flavors adds an extra level of indentation (that's what the `("  "++)` is for). We can test it:

```
TestModule> putStrLn $ concatMap show [cake1, cake2, cake3]
Cake1
  Chocolate
  Nutella
    Strawberry
Cake2
  Chocolate
  Vanilla
Cake3
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `prints :: Cake -> String` and `flavors :: [Cake]`, we know

```
map prints flavors :: [String]
```

But this doesn't jive with the context in which it is used, since in

```
" " ++ expr
```

the `" "` is clearly a `String` and we therefore expect `expr` to be a `String` and not a `[String]`.

To fix this, you should write or find a function which converts your `[String]` into a `String` in some way -- there are many candidate behaviors for this type, so you should decide what behavior you want and then find a way to achieve that behavior.