# Haskell Custom Show Instance

Tags: haskell, tree, show

I've got a question, still working on the genealogy tree, here's what I've got so far (Sorry for the Portuguese words xD):

```
data Familia = Node String [Familia]

instance Show Familia where
  show (Node a b) = show a ++ "\n\t" ++ show b
raiz :: String -> Familia
raiz n = (Node n [])

juntar :: String -> String -> Familia -> Familia
juntar a b (Node c l) 
        | b == c = (Node c (l ++ [raiz a]))
        | otherwise = (Node c (juntarAux a b l))

juntarAux :: String -> String -> [Familia] -> [Familia]
juntarAux a b [] = []
juntarAux a b [(Node x l)]
        | x == b = [(juntar a b (Node x l))]
        | otherwise = [(Node x (juntarAux a b l))]
juntarAux a b ((Node x l):xs)
        | x == b = (juntar a b (Node x l)):xs
        | otherwise = (Node x l):(juntarAux a b xs)
```

This is working the way I want it to, the thing is, this is my current output:

```
*Main> let f = raiz "Bob"
*Main> let g = juntar "John" "Bob" f
*Main> g
"Bob"
    ["John"
    []]
```

And what I want is, to print it like so:

```
Bob
    John
         Ruth
    Hank
```

So, the Root of the family is Bob, Bob's son is John and Hank, John has a daughter called Ruth.

I've tried doing it several ways with stuff I saw in other posts, but this is the latest try:

```
instance Show Familia where
  show (Node a b) = show a ++ "\n\t" ++ (unlines $ map (unwords . map show) b)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
t4.hs:14:77:
Couldn't match type ‘Familia’ with ‘[a0]’
Expected type: [[a0]]
  Actual type: [Familia]
In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘b’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘map (unwords . map show) b’
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: I think (although I hesitate to use my dup-hammer) that this is structurally the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423268/instance-show-haskell

Comment: Closer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370551/haskell-show-instance-on-list) which I linked in the comments of the question you posted

Comment: @AdamSmith good point xD Must've missed these posts, will look into them and hopefully get something off it :D Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `map show` is a function that expects an argument of type `[a]` - because `map` takes a function and a list.

Therefore, the expression `(unwords . map show)` is *also* a function that expects an argument of type `[a]`.

Therefore, the expression `map (unwords . map show)` is a function that expects an argument of type `[[a]]` - it expects a list, each element of which is also a list, because it must be an acceptable argument for function `(unwords . map show)`.

Therefore, in the expression `map (unwords . map show) b`, the last argument `b` must be of type `[[a]]` for some `a`.

But from the pattern `Node a b`, it follows that `b` is of type `[Familia]` - which is incompatible with `[[a]]`. This is what the compiler is telling you in the error message.

When you find yourself confused with types of nested functions, it is usually a good idea to pull them all apart, give a name (and maybe a type) to each piece. That will allow you to see where the mistake is.

```
instance Show Familia where
   show (Node a b) = show a ++ "\n\t" ++ concatSubFamilias 
      where
         showSubFamilias :: [String]
         showSubFamilias = map show b

         concatSubFamilias :: String
         concatSubFamilias = unlines showSubFamilias
```

Note that the above solution won't give you the result you're after, because it doesn't insert indentation before nested `Familia`s. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Looks good to me, thank you, just one question, how do I remove the quotation marks? Tried a few things but couldn't remove them from the output

Comment: Quotation marks come from `show a`. The `show` function is generally not intended to produce user-friendly output, but rather as technical display. Thus, `show` will usually produce text that is valid Haskell code, or at least very close to it. Specifically, `show`ing a `String` will enclose the string in double quotes. To avoid this, simply use `a` directly (since it's already a `String`) instead of putting it through `show` first.

Comment: Oh, thanks :D Sorry for my lack of knowledge, still a beginner in the Haskell World :p